# numpy array each element multiplication with matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix

```
A = [[ 1.  1.]
    [ 1.  1.]]
```

and two arrays (`a` and `b`), every array contains 20 float numbers How can I multiply the using formula:

```
( x'    = A * ( x )
  y' )          y
```

Is this correct? `m = A * [a, b]`

Comment: What's the relationship between `a`,`b` and (presumably) `x` and `y`? Does every value in `a` represent an `x` and every value in `b` represent a `y` for example?

Comment: there is no relation between a and b. Just arrays of uniformly generated numbers.

Comment: yes, every value of a represent x and every value of b represent y

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matrix multiplication with NumPy arrays can be done with [np.dot](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html#numpy-dot).
If `X` has shape (i,j) and `Y` has shape (j,k) then `np.dot(X,Y)` will be the matrix product and have shape (i,k). The last axis of `X` and the second-to-last axis of `Y` is multiplied and summed over.

Now, if `a` and `b` have shape `(20,)`, then `np.vstack([a,b])` has shape `(2, 20)`:

```
In [66]: np.vstack([a,b]).shape
Out[66]: (2, 20)
```

You can think of `np.vstack([a, b])` as a 2x20 matrix with the values of `a` on the first row, and the values of `b` on the second row.

Since `A` has shape (2,2), we can perform the matrix multiplication

```
m = np.dot(A, np.vstack([a,b]))
```

to arrive at an array of shape (2, 20).
The first row of `m` contains the `x'` values, the second row contains the `y'` values.

---

NumPy also has a `matrix` subclass of `ndarray` (a special kind of NumPy array) which has convenient syntax for doing matrix multiplication with 2D arrays. If we define `A` to be a `matrix` (rather than a plain `ndarray` which is what `np.array(...)` creates), then matrix multiplication can be done with the `*` operator.

I show both ways (with `A` being a plain `ndarray` and `A2` being a `matrix`) below:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]])
A2 = np.matrix([[1.,1.],[1.,1.]])
a = np.random.random(20)
b = np.random.random(20)
c = np.vstack([a,b])

m = np.dot(A, c)
m2 = A2 * c

assert np.allclose(m, m2)
```